# Proof of $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{L}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I'm unsure about a formal proof that I did, could someone please verify. The reason is that it doesn't give a formula to calculate a $\delta$, given $\epsilon$.

> To be proven:
>
> If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, where $L \neq 0$ then $$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{L} $$

I'm supposed to use the fact (which I've already proven) that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ then there exists some $\delta$ such that $|f(x)| > |L|/2$ for $x$ inside the $\delta$-interval.

My attempt goes like this:

Let $\epsilon$ be given.

Note that since $f(x) \to L$, by the fact above, there exists some $\delta_0$ such that $|f(x)| > \frac{|L|}{2}$, in other words, $\frac{1}{|f(x)|} < \frac{2}{|L|}$ for $x$ within $\delta_0$ of $a$

Now, since $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, there exists some $\delta_1$ such that $|f(x)-L| < \frac{|L|^2 \epsilon}{2}$ for $x$ within $\delta_1$ of $a$

So put $\delta = \min(\delta_0,\delta_1)$  <--- depends on $\epsilon$ only indirectly, is this legit??

Then we have
$$|\frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{L}| = |\frac{L-f(x)}{f(x)L}| = |\frac{L-f(x)}{L}||\frac{1}{f(x)}| < |L-f(x)||\frac{2}{L^2}| < |\frac{2}{L^2}|\frac{|L|^2 \epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Is this proof OK? What makes me unsure is that I can't provide a $\delta$, given $\epsilon$, from $\delta = \min(\delta_0,\delta_1)$.

Thank you

Comment: Good job. It seems fine. The way you defined $\delta$ does depend on $\epsilon$, if you insist to put this way. You just used the given condition, which is valid and intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you write "depends on $\epsilon$ only indirectly", whether the dependence is "direct" or "indirect" is irrelevant. Your formula $\delta = \text{min}(\delta_0,\delta_1)$ shows that $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$, as it should.

For example, had you given actual formulas for $\delta_0$ and for $\delta_1$ which define both as functions of $\epsilon$, then by plugging those formulas into the equation $\delta=\text{min}(\delta_0,\delta_1)$ then you *would* have an actual formula for $\delta$ which defines it as a function of $\epsilon$. This happens all the time in mathematics: new functions defined by composing old functions. Often we don't bother to write out the formula for these compositions, because we know that composition is allowable.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could say that $g:x → \frac{1}{x}$ in continuous in $[\frac{L}{2}, 2L]$ and, as you noticed, there exists some δ such that 2|L|>|f(x)>|L|/2 for x inside the δ-interval.

Therefore, $lim_{x→a}(g(f(x)) = g(lim_{x→a}(f(x)) = \frac{1}{L}$